# Very basic and crude graphical 2D adventure game with text box

Tags: c++, sdl

I wanted to make a sort of crude version of RuneScape. It has a text box where the majority of the information the player learns is from and basic graphics. I'm using [sdl](/questions/tagged/sdl) for my graphics library and it's working pretty well so far.

Right now, it has a sprite that can be controlled via the arrow keys, as well as the ability to return into the text box whatever you type it, and the fact that is scrolls down, like an ordinary text box you see in the chat feature in a game.

The only major issue right now is that the sprite (denoted as `rcSprite` as a `SDL_Rect` object) has a delay when it **starts** moving. Also, the text doesn't wrap or anything, it can become practically infinitely long, but this can be treated as a missing feature rather than an issue.

In the future, I'd like to use tables in a `.txt` file to handle the text as well as use multiple languages.

Here is the source code with relevant commentary:

**gfx.h**:

```
#ifndef GFX_H
#define GFX_H

#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <algorithm>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_ttf.h>

class CTextBox
{
public:
  CTextBox(); // Class constructor
  ~CTextBox(); // Class deconstructor
  void free(); // Deallocate memory
  void render(SDL_Renderer* renderer, TTF_Font* font, std::string text, SDL_Color color); // Provides the rendered texture
  int getWidth();
  int getHeight();
  SDL_Texture* getTexture();
  std::string text;
private:
  SDL_Texture* mTexture;

  int mWidth;
  int mHeight;
};

CTextBox::CTextBox()
{
  mTexture = NULL;
  mWidth = 800;
  mHeight = 20;
  text = " ";
}

void CTextBox::free()
{
  if (mTexture != NULL)
  {
    SDL_DestroyTexture(mTexture);
    mTexture = NULL;
  }
}

CTextBox::~CTextBox()
{
  free();
}

void CTextBox::render(SDL_Renderer* renderer, TTF_Font* font, std::string text, SDL_Color color)
{
  free(); // Deallocates any remaining memory

  SDL_Surface* TextSurface = TTF_RenderText_Solid(font, text.c_str(), color);
  if (TextSurface == NULL)
  {
    throw(::std::runtime_error("Unable to render surface! ERROR: "));
  }
  mTexture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, TextSurface);
  if (mTexture == NULL)
  {
    throw(::std::runtime_error("Unable to render texture! ERROR: "));
  }
  SDL_FreeSurface(TextSurface); // Deallocate surface memory

  SDL_QueryTexture(mTexture, NULL, NULL, &mWidth, &mHeight); // Resizes texture to match text dimensions
}

int CTextBox::getWidth()
{
  return mWidth;
}

int CTextBox::getHeight()
{
  return mHeight;
}

SDL_Texture* CTextBox::getTexture()
{
  return mTexture;
}

class CTextMenu
{
  std::vector<CTextBox> boxes; // Vector of CTextBox obects, this is central to the multi-line text box feature.
public:
  void update(SDL_Renderer *renderer, TTF_Font *font, SDL_Color color, SDL_Rect output); // Renders the entire boxes vector
  void newBox(std::string text); // Intiialises a new CTextBox object with its text
};

void CTextMenu::update(SDL_Renderer *renderer, TTF_Font *font, SDL_Color color, SDL_Rect output)
{
  SDL_RenderSetClipRect(renderer, &output); // Sets the clip SDL_Rect
  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < boxes.size(); i++)
  {
    boxes[i].render(renderer, font, boxes[i].text, color);
    SDL_Rect dstrect = { 0, 600 + i * boxes[i].getHeight(), boxes[i].getWidth(), boxes[i].getHeight() }; // Sets the SDL_Rect for the text
    SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, boxes[i].getTexture(), NULL, &dstrect); // Stacks dstrect into the renderer
  }
}

void CTextMenu::newBox(std::string text)
{
  CTextBox box; // Intiialises a new CTextBox object
  box.text = text; // Sets the text in
  boxes.insert(boxes.begin(), box); // Inserts the object into the front of boxes vector

  // Removes the last element of boxes vector if boxes exceeds 16, therefore 16 is maximum number of lines allowed
  if (boxes.size() > 16)
  {
    boxes.pop_back();
  }
}

#endif
```

**gfx.cpp**:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_ttf.h>

#include "gfx.h"

// Screen dimensions, constants
const int SCREEN_WIDTH = 800;
const int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 900; // 600 for ground, 280 for output, 20 for input

SDL_Window* gWindow = NULL; // The window we'll be rendering to
SDL_Surface* gScreenSurface = NULL; // The surface contained by the window
SDL_Surface* gCurrentSurface = NULL; // Current displayed image
TTF_Font* gFont = NULL; // Font pointer.
SDL_Color gTextColor = { 255, 255, 255, 0xFF }; // Text color, white.

CTextMenu CMenu; // Primary CTextBox handler.
CTextBox CTextInput; // Handles text input.

SDL_Renderer* gRenderer = NULL; // The renderer we'll be using

// Various geometry.
SDL_Rect rcGround, rcSprite, rcTextInput, rcTextOutput, rcTextOutputGrd;

void init();
void loadMedia();
void quit();

void init()
{
  if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) > 0)
  {
    throw(::std::runtime_error("SDL failed to initialise! ERROR: "));
  }
  gWindow = SDL_CreateWindow("Caventure",
                              SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
                              SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
                              SCREEN_WIDTH,
                              SCREEN_HEIGHT,
                              SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
  if (gWindow == NULL)
  {
    throw(::std::runtime_error("Window failed to initialise! ERROR: "));
  }
  gScreenSurface = SDL_GetWindowSurface(gWindow);
  if (gScreenSurface == NULL)
  {
  throw(::std::runtime_error("Surface failed to initialise! ERROR: "));
  }
  gRenderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(gWindow, -1, 0);
  if (gRenderer == NULL)
  {
    throw(::std::runtime_error("Renderer could not be initialised! ERROR: "));
  }
  if (TTF_Init() > 0)
  {
    throw(::std::runtime_error("TTF could not be initialised! ERROR: "));
  }
}

void loadMedia()
{
  // Set geomtry dimensions, apart from rcTextInput.
  rcGround = { 0, 0, 800, 600 };
  rcSprite = { 400, 300, 4, 4 };
  rcTextOutput = { 0, 600, 800, 280 };
  rcTextOutputGrd = { 0, 600, 800, 280 };

  gFont = TTF_OpenFont("src/graphics/resources/notomono-regular.ttf", 14);
  if (gFont == NULL)
  {
    throw(::std::runtime_error("Font failed to load! ERROR: "));
  }

  SDL_SetTextInputRect(&rcTextInput);
}

void quit()
{
  // Deallocate memory
    SDL_DestroyWindow(gWindow);
    SDL_DestroyRenderer(gRenderer);
  TTF_CloseFont(gFont);
    gWindow = NULL;
  gRenderer = NULL;
  gFont = NULL;

    // Quit SDL subsystems
  TTF_Quit();
    SDL_Quit();
}

int main()
{
  try
  {
    init();
    loadMedia();

    bool quit = false;
    bool renderText = false;
    SDL_Event event;
    std::string inputText = " ";
    SDL_StartTextInput();

    while(!quit)
    {
      while(SDL_PollEvent(&event) != 0)
      {
        if(event.type == SDL_QUIT)
        {
          quit = true;
        }
        else if(event.type == SDL_KEYDOWN)
        {
          // Sprite movement
          switch(event.key.keysym.sym)
          {
            case SDLK_UP:
            rcSprite.y -= 5;
            break;

            case SDLK_DOWN:
            rcSprite.y += 5;
            break;

            case SDLK_LEFT:
            rcSprite.x -= 5;
            break;

            case SDLK_RIGHT:
            rcSprite.x += 5;
            break;
          }

          // Backspace handler
          if (event.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_BACKSPACE && inputText.length() > 0)
          {
            inputText.pop_back();
            if (inputText.length() == 0)
            {
              inputText = " ";
            }
          }

          // Creates new line of text
          else if (event.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_RETURN && inputText.length() != 0 && inputText != " ")
          {
            CMenu.newBox(inputText);
            renderText = true;
            inputText = " ";
          }
        }
        else if (event.type == SDL_TEXTINPUT)
        {
          inputText += event.text.text;
        }
      }

      // Renders sprite movement
      if (rcSprite.x < 0 || rcSprite.y < 0 || rcSprite.y > rcGround.h || rcSprite.x > rcGround.w)
      {
        rcSprite.x = 400;
        rcSprite.y = 300;
      }

      // Sets background to black
      SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(gRenderer, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00);
      SDL_RenderClear(gRenderer);

      // Renders background of sprite to black
      SDL_RenderFillRect(gRenderer, &rcGround);
      SDL_BlitSurface(gCurrentSurface, NULL, gScreenSurface, &rcGround);

      // Renders background of text box to grey
      SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(gRenderer, 0x40, 0x40, 0x40, 0x40);
      SDL_RenderFillRect(gRenderer, &rcTextOutputGrd);
      SDL_BlitSurface(gCurrentSurface, NULL, gScreenSurface, &rcTextOutputGrd);

      // Renders text input
      CTextInput.render(gRenderer, gFont, inputText.c_str(), gTextColor);
      rcTextInput = { 0, 880, CTextInput.getWidth(), CTextInput.getHeight() };
      SDL_RenderCopy(gRenderer, CTextInput.getTexture(), NULL, &rcTextInput);

      // Renders text output
      if (renderText)
      {
        CMenu.update(gRenderer, gFont, gTextColor, rcTextOutput);
      }
      SDL_RenderSetClipRect(gRenderer, NULL);

      // Renders text box background edges white
      SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(gRenderer, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF);
      SDL_RenderDrawLine(gRenderer, 0, 600, 800, 600);
      SDL_RenderDrawLine(gRenderer, 0, 880, 800, 880);

      // Renders sprite
      SDL_RenderFillRect(gRenderer, &rcSprite);
      SDL_BlitSurface(gCurrentSurface, NULL, gScreenSurface, &rcSprite);

      // Presents render
      SDL_RenderPresent(gRenderer);
    }
    SDL_StopTextInput();
  }
  catch (std::runtime_error const& msg)
    {
        printf("%s", msg.what());
        if (SDL_GetError() != NULL)
        {
            printf("%s", SDL_GetError());
        }
    else if (TTF_GetError() != NULL)
        {
            printf("%s", TTF_GetError());
        }
    else
    {
      printf("%s", "NULL");
    }
    quit();
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
  quit();
  return 0;
}
```

Any relevant help and advice will be highly appreciated and welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is very readable, and makes a lot of sense. Here are some things I'd change:

## Source Organization

Don't put more than 1 class in a header file. Only put methods that need to be inlined into the header. Put the rest into a source (.cpp) file. You should have:

- CTextBox.h
- CTextBox.cpp
- CTextMenu.h
- CTextMenu.cpp

They would be small, but they will inevitably grow in the future and having them in a single file will become unwieldy.

## Making Use of C++

These comments are not helpful at all:

```
CTextBox(); // Class constructor
~CTextBox(); // Class deconstructor
void free(); // Deallocate memory
```

Just remove them.

Why is `free()` a public method? Should any caller be able to free the texture that is used internally? It doesn't seem like it! I'd make it private to reduce the chance that someone who shouldn't call it will. The name is also not very clear. What are you freeing? It sounds like the same thing as the destructor. You're only freeing the texture, so maybe call it `freeTexture()` or something along those lines.

These methods do not mutate the object, so they should be marked as `const`:

```
int getWidth() const;
int getHeight() const;
SDL_Texture* getTexture() const;
```

In your `CTextBox::render()` method, you are allocating an `SDL_Surface*`, checking to make sure it succeeded, then using it, and then manually freeing it. C++ allows you to create smart pointer types. They're part of the Standard Template Library in C++11 and later. But even if you're not using C++11 or later, you can create a simple class that manages the lifetime of an object like this on the stack. It reduces errors and makes the code a lot cleaner. If you had a `SmartSurface` class, it could have a constructor that attempts to allocate the surface and throws if it can't. It's destructor would simply free the pointer. You could then use it as a stack-based variable in the `render()` method and it would look something like this:

```
void CTextBox::render(…)
{
    freeTexture();

    SmartSurface TextSurface(font, text.c_str(), color);
    mTexture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, TextSurface.get());
    if (mTexture == NULL)
    {
        throw(::std::runtime_error("Unable to render texture! ERROR: "));
    }

    SDL_QueryTexture(mTexture, NULL, NULL, &mWidth, &mHeight); // Resizes texture to match text dimensions
}
```

## Cleaning Up

You should avoid global variables as it becomes very difficult to figure out where they change. All of your globals could probably be local variables in your `main()` function and passed to other functions.

And while we're looking at your globals, don't do this:

```
SDL_Color gTextColor = { 255, 255, 255, 0xFF }; // Text color, white.
```

You've declared 3 of the 4 fields in decimal and one in hexadecimal. Worse, you've declared it to be the same value as the other 3, just in a different base. That's not helping anyone.

Your `main()` function is huge. I recommend breaking it down into smaller functions. `init()` and `loadMedia()` are a good start, but you should also have something like `runGameLoop()` and move the entire `while` loop into that. Additionally, you should break down the `while` loop into smaller functions, too, such as one that handles key presses, one that draws the background, one that draws the text, etc.

Comment: Thank you for the advice! I do have a few more questions though. What do you mean by "Only put methods that need to be inlined into the header"? By the way, taking your advice, I separated the class into header and source files where `class` goes into the header file and all functions are put into source. Secondly, I'm making some difficulties transitioning the global variables into `main()`, practically all my functions require them. Is there a standard approach to this or should I just use classes to sort this through?

Comment: When the C++ compiler compiles your files, there are some methods that are very short, such as a getter method. If the entire function is in the header file, then when compiling a source file that calls that function, the compiler can decide whether it wants to generate a function call, or it can just put the entire body of the called function into the function it is calling. This usually results in faster code because a function call requires setting up the stack and tearing it down afterwards.

Comment: There are a few ways you can reduce global data. You can obviously pass every piece of data you need into a function. You can also group data into either `struct`s or `class`es and pass around a single (or a few) variable(s) that is either one of those structs or an object of that class.